# Autorun Serveo in Raspberrypi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I want to run below script automatically whenever my raspberrypi boot up.

```
ssh -R 80:localhost:80 serveo.net
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this.  rc.local is probably one of the most universal of them.  Edit the /etc/rc.local file to run your script.

e.g.

```
sudo pico /etc/rc.local
```

then add:

```
/path/to/script.sh
```

Leave the "exit 0" at the bottom.  Your script will need to be executable (chmod +x file.sh), also you may need to fork the entry you made to rc.local by adding an & to the end of your script call, depending on if your commands will definitely exit or not.